# How to create a dictionary in LINQ when populating a class?

Tags: c#, linq

Description:

At the moment I have a class which looks like so:

```
 public class SupplierSummaryReport {
            public string SupplierName { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, decimal> DateValues { get; set; }
        }
```

Using LINQ, I am trying to create an IQueryable list of the SupplierSummaryReport class. However, when trying to create the dictionary in C#, the application fails. I'm not sure how to create the dictionary, can anyone help?

LINQ/C#:

```
 public IQueryable<APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport> GetSupplierSummaryReportData() {
            var data = (from i in _ctx.Invoices
                        where i.Turnover == true
                        select new {
                            Year = i.InvoiceDate.Year.ToString(),
                            AccountName = i.AccountName,
                            Value = i.NetAmount_Home ?? 0
                        });

            return data.GroupBy(r => new { r.Year, r.AccountName })
                .Select(g => new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport {
                    SupplierName = g.Key.AccountName,
                    //I believe it fails when creating the dictionary
                    DateValues = new Dictionary<string, decimal> {
                        {g.Key.Year, g.Sum(r=> r.Value)}
                    }
                }).OrderBy(r => r.SupplierName);
        }
```

Expected Outcome:

```
Supplier Name = "Test", DateValues = {2010, 500}
Supplier Name = "Test2", DateValues = {2011, 900}
```

Actual Outcome:

Receive this error:

> Only list initializer items with a single element are supported in
>   LINQ to Entities.

Comment: An error at runtime or compile time? What is the error message?

Comment: what is this `_ctx.Invoices`?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers The error message is:Only list initializer items with a single element are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @Ian It is an entity in the application which maps to a table

Comment: What line is it that the error occurs? I'm guessing in your `return` statement?

Comment: @AndrewKilburn too bad, it cannot be reproduced then. :s maybe you can also give some data samples for `_ctx.Invoices` (input) together with the error message, expected vs actual outputs?

Comment: @krillgar Actually, only when I enumerate the data does it show me the error message

Comment: I don't you can do this in a L2S query: `new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{g.Key.Year, g.Sum(r=> r.Value)}}`

Comment: @Maarten Yeah, I think I will have to create a list of another class

Comment: Once you start the `.Select(g => ` there's no point creating a dictionary as you have only one `g.Key`. You would only be creating a dictionary with one element in it if you tried. I think you have your logic wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Once you start the `.Select(g =>` there's no point creating a dictionary as you have only one `g.Key`. You would only be creating a dictionary with one element in it if you tried. I think you have your logic wrong.

I think this is what your `return` statement should look like:

```
return
    data
        .GroupBy(r => r.AccountName)
        .Select(g => new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport
        {
            SupplierName = g.Key.AccountName,
            //I believe it fails when creating the dictionary
            DateValues = g
                .GroupBy(x => x.Year, x => x.Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum())
        })
        .OrderBy(r => r.SupplierName);
```

Now you may need to put a `.ToArray()` after `data` to bring the records in to memory to make this query work.