# LINQ to Entities - Initializing complex objects (Dictionary or List<KeyValuePair>)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am required to represent data on a tree, with each node having `id`, `text` and several `attributes`.

I've tried keep my `attributes` property generic, and initialize it using LINQ to Entities.

---

**Attempt 1**:

With my class as:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> attributes { get; set; }
    public int? parent { get; set; }
}
```

I tried initializing:

```
List<TreeNode> taskItems = new List<TreeNode>();
using (var database = new MyDatabase())
{
    taskItems =
    (
        from t in database.Task
        select new TreeNode()
        {
            id = t.ID,
            text = t.Name,
            attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "Color", t.Color },
                { "Category", t.Category }
            },
            parent = t.ParentID
        }
    )
    .ToList();
}
```

The above fails with the error

> **Only list initializer items with a single element are supported in LINQ to Entities.**

---

**Attempt 2**:

I tried `List<KeyValuePair>` instead of the `Dictionary`:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> attributes { get; set; }
    public int? parent { get; set; }
}
```

I tried initializing:

```
List<TreeNode> taskItems = new List<TreeNode>();
using (var database = new MyDatabase())
{
    taskItems =
    (
        from t in database.Task
        select new TreeNode()
        {
            id = t.ID,
            text = t.Name,
            attributes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Color", t.Color),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Category", t.Category)
            },
            parent = t.ParentID
        }
    )
    .ToList();
}
```

This time the above fails with the error

> **Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.**

---

How can I achieve the initialization of `attributes` property?

Comment: [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014278/how-to-create-a-dictionary-in-linq-when-populating-a-class/35014914) should help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
database.Task
.Select(t=> new 
{
            t.ID,
            t.Name,
            t.Color,
            t.Category,
            t.ParentID
}).AsEnumerable()
.Select(t=> new TreeNode
        {
            id = t.ID,
            text = t.Name,
            attributes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Color", t.Color),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Category", t.Category)
            },
            parent = t.ParentID
        }).ToList()
```

Comment: This worked. I've posted my working code as a syntax alternative.

Comment: The thing is: if you have just two type Attribute which is Color and Category in this case; what is the purpose of defining List? Just simply define two property as color and category like i did. I didn't understand why u used Dictionary or List.

Comment: The above code is a simplified version of my production code, which has a lot more attribute properties.

Answer (score 2):

KeyValuePair is immutable. You can't change his values after your create the instance.
Create custom class:

```
class KeyValuePairCustom<T,S> 
{
    public KeyValuePairCustom() {}

    public T Key {get;set;}
    public S Value {get;set;}
}
```

Than in your linq statement use the following code:

```
List<TreeNode> taskItems = new List<TreeNode>();
using (var database = new MyDatabase())
{
    taskItems =
    (
        from t in database.Task
        select new TreeNode()
        {
            id = t.ID,
            text = t.Name,
            attributes = new List<KeyValuePairCustom<string, object>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePairCustom<string, object>() { 
                    Key="Color", 
                    Value = t.Color
                },
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>() {
                    Key = "Category", 
                    Value = t.Category
                }
            },
            parent = t.ParentID
        }
    )
    .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@ArgeKumandan`'s solution works.

This is a syntax alternative, and uses `Dictionary`:

```
List<TreeNode> taskItems = new List<TreeNode>();
using (var database = new MyDatabase())
{
    taskItems =
    (
        from t in database.Task
        select new
        {
            id = t.ID,
            text = t.Name,
            color = t.Color,
            category = t.Category,
            parent = t.ParentID
        }
    )
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(t => new TreeNode()
    {
        id = t.id,
        text = t.text,
        attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "color", t.color },
            { "category", t.category }
        },
        parent = t.parent
    })
    .ToList();
}
```